# Avoid entering white space in regex password Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am trying Regex Strong Password.

My regex is below. Works perfectly for below features.

> Min 1 Digit
>  Min 1 Lower char 
> Min 1 Upper char 
> Min 1 Special char 
> Min 8
>   chars 
> Max 15 chars

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w]).{8,15}$
```

Can somebody suggest to avoid entering white spaces?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

`^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[^\w])(?!.*?\s).{8,15}$`

I just added a negative lookahead for whitespace in addition to all your positive lookaheads.

As for what it means, it basically has a bunch of "lookaheads" which means "only create a match if the selected thing is followed by".  It has four different lookaheads:

```
(?=.*?[A-Z]) // followed by any number of characters and then a capital letter
(?=.*?[a-z]) // followed by any number of characters and then a lowercase letter
(?=.*?[0-9]) // followed by any number of characters and then a number
(?=.*?[^\w]) // followed by any number of characters and then not a word character (0-9a-zA-Z_)
```

the `^` at the beginning means starts with.  So it basically says the start of the regex should be followed by all four conditions specified above.  I just added one more condidtion that says the start may NOT be followed by a space.  It's called a "negative lookahead":

```
(?!.*?\s)
```

Comment: Do you have any link that explains about (?=.*?[a-z]) ? +1 for the help. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the best reference I have found is MDN. 
 It is for javascript but js and php regexes are about the same I in my experience. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp.  Also a detailed breakdown
 https://regex101.com/r/nKgk6R/1